# Make column values blank for the first 3 days for column group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have time series data

```
df     
timestamp           person    value 
2020-10-10 00:10      1        20
2020-10-10 00:20      1        30
..  
2020-10-20 20:00      1        50
2020-11-05 00:10      2        10
2020-11-05 00:20      2        60
...
```

I want to set the "value" column to "NaN" for each person for their first 3 days. Each person has different start-end times in the dataset.

How can I achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df['value'].where(df.groupby('person').cumcount().ge(3))
```